# Image save on button click

Tags: iphone

I want to save an image from camera or already saved image to photo library in iPhone.
Here I implemented some code, but I can't implement it on button click moreover, and it's crashing.

I am very new to iPhone programming side. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info:(id)sender{
    UIImage *selectedImage;
    NSURL *mediaUrl;

    mediaUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    if (mediaUrl == nil)
    {
        selectedImage = (UIImage *) [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if (selectedImage == nil)
        {
            selectedImage = (UIImage *) [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            NSLog(@"Original image picked.");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Edited image picked.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Video picked. Not yet implemented.");
    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    if((UIButton *) sender == savePhotoBtn) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya my function is getting exectuted... I checked with printf statment..

```
/*  Globaly declared  */
NSDictionary *info1;
UIImagePickerController * picker;

-(IBAction) savePhoto:(id) sender
{
    UIImage *selectedImage;
    NSURL *mediaUrl;
    mediaUrl = (NSURL *)[info1 valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    if (mediaUrl == nil)
    {
        selectedImage = (UIImage *) [info1 valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if (selectedImage == nil)
        {
            selectedImage = (UIImage *) [info1 valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            NSLog(@"Original image picked.");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Edited image picked.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Video picked. Not yet implemented.");
    }
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    //if((UIButton *) sender == savePhotoBtn) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    //}
    printf(" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ");
}
```